# R Dplyr: How do I add columns from an ungrouped dataframe to a grouped dataframe and retain the grouping?

Tags: r, group-by, dplyr, grouped-table

I have a main data frame (`data`) that contains information about purchases: names, year, city, and a few other variables:

```
Name Year City
N1   2018 NY
N2   2019 SF
N2   2018 SF
N1   2010 NY
N3   2020 AA
```

I used `new_data <- data %>% group by(Name) %>% tally(name = "Count")` to get something like this:

```
Name Count
N1   2
N2   2
N3   1
```

My questions, preferably using dplyr:

1) How do I now add the city that corresponds to Name to `new_data`, i.e:

```
Name Count City
N1   2     NY
N2   2     SF
N3   1     AA
```

2) How do I add the earliest year of each Name to new_data, i.e.:

```
Name Count City Year
N1   2     NY   2010
N2   2     SF   2018
N3   1     AA   2020
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that `summarise` may suit you better, for example:

```
data %>%
  group_by(Name, City) %>%
  summarise(Count = n(),
            Year = min(Year))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 x 4
# Groups:   Name [3]
  Name  City  Count  Year
  <fct> <fct> <int> <int>
1 N1    NY        2  2010
2 N2    SF        2  2018
3 N3    AA        1  2020
```

While you can group with `City` as well to keep it in the output.

Comment: Thank you, arg0naut91!

Answer (score 0):

An option with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)[, .(Count = .N, Year = min(Year)), .(Name, City)]
```